# JQuery selector

Tags: html, jquery, css-selectors

В чем заключается разница между:

```
$(document).on('click', '.selector', function(){})
```

и

```
$('.selector').on('click', function(){})
```

В чем принципиальная разница и влияет ли это на скорость работы?

Comment: принципиальная разница: во втором случае - клик навесится только на те элементы которые уже в доме

Comment: А через document элемент к которому привязан клик каждый раз будет искаться от корня документа?

Comment: @pawheel, в первом случае, если вы динамически будете добавлять html с этими ссылками, то они тоже будут обрабатываться, а во втором не будут, только я обычно использую не `$(document)`, а `$('body')`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(document).on('click', '.selector', function(){})` или `$('.parentSelector').on('click', '.childSelector', function(){})` - 
[делегирование события](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

**Следует использовать:**

1. Если имеем большое кол-во однотипных элементов, на которых нужно слушать одни и те же события.
   Например якорная навигация с большим числом пунктов, для реализации плавного скролла или фильтр в магазине, для отправки ajax запросы при каждому клике по пункту фильтра и т.д - вариантов масса.
2. Если элементы, на которых требуется слушать события, могут создаваться динамически, во время работы сайта.

Вся суть заключается в том, что вешается **одно** событие на родительский селектор (или выше стоящий селектор), который реагирует на всплывающие события от дочерних элементов.
По производительности такой способ лучше при выполнение описанных выше условий.
Но я не рекомендую вешать на `document` или на `body` без крайней необходимости, потому что [отрицательно влияет на производительность](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12824698/4222611). Старайтесь использовать более *прямой* родительский селектор.

`$('.selector').on('click', function(){})` следует использовать во всех остальных случаях, т.к. достигается наилучшая производительность.